# Jade errors when using Express framework

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am working on a site built in Express.js, and I'm using Jade as my template engine.  However, despite my best efforts, I can't seem to figure out why my templates are failing.

Express usually logs an error to the console, but when something happens with jade, there are no errors reported by the server, and a blank page is rendered.  I have set Express to development mode, but I am still unable to figure out why the template is failing.

I would simply like to know how to view error messages.  Are there configuration options I need to set?  Is there some other way to validate the templates?  It's making the whole process aggravating to debug with no information.

Comment: By default, when theres a jade compile error, express will output that error message in place of the render.  you should see a 500 page returned with some details and a stack trace.  Without code to look at, that's as much help as I can offer.

Comment: I figure that is the case; however, I only see the access log in the console when I "npm start".  Would this stack trace be somewhere else?

Comment: what about when you try to visit the route?  what does the browser show?

Comment: A blank page rendered with some basic elements [body, head, html], but no information.  When I fix the errors [which in this case were indentation errors], everything renders as it should.

The console shows an access and a rendering each time, but no hint of an error.